# Write S3 objects with CDK

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cdk

I am trying to code a CDK doing the job of writing some empty objects inside some folders that I need to be visible in my bucket.

I have found this answer 
https://serverfault.com/questions/957686/how-to-upload-a-file-into-s3-bucket-using-cloudformation-script showing the way in CloudFormation.

I wonder if somebody has done something similar with CDK.

Thank you

Answer (score 54, accepted):

You can achieve this with [`@aws-cdk/aws-s3-deployment`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/aws-s3-deployment-readme.html).

Using TypeScript:

```ts
import s3 = require('@aws-cdk/aws-s3');
import s3deploy = require('@aws-cdk/aws-s3-deployment');

const myBucket = new s3.Bucket(this, 'Bucket');

new s3deploy.BucketDeployment(this, 'DeployFiles', {
  sources: [s3deploy.Source.asset('./folder')], # 'folder' contains your empty files at the right locations
  destinationBucket: bucket,
});
```

Asset feature will require the execution of the command:

`cdk bootstrap aws://<account>/<region>`

that will run a cloudFormation and create a bucket with name `cdktoolkit-stagingbucket-<random_chars>`.

Comment: That was very useful, I added an integration to your answer. Thank you,

Comment: I am trying to upload a jar file which is roughly 200MB and each time it failed I think it might be time out? Then I set the `memoryLimit` but it thrown out of memory exception.

Comment: The `memoryLimit` applies to the runtime memory of the lambda which does the copy under the hood but the lambda is construct to unzip the contents once copied but the `/tmp` directory has a hard limit of `512 MB`. So in case the data to extract from zip + zip contents, if that exceeds 500MB, this method won't be helpful as of now.

Ref: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/gettingstarted-limits.html

This issue is open as of now: https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/issues/7950

Comment: how to get the version of the object in the destinationBucket?

Comment: does this work for a jar file?